# With $rad(N)=\prod_{p|N}p$, if $N$ is even and $\frac{2+rad(N)}{8}\left(\sum_{\substack{d|N,d<rad(N)}}d\right)=N$ then is perfect?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, experimental-mathematics, perfect-numbers

In the literature (see for example sites and paper concerning to  the *abc conjecture*, I say this as reference and by caution to avoid mistakes) is defined the arithmetical function $rad(n)$ as $1$ if $n=1$ and $rad(n)=\prod_{p|n}p$ the product of distinct primes dividing $n$. For example $$rad(18)=rad(2\cdot 3^2)=2\cdot 3=6,$$
and yes, is multiplicative.

We have the following

> **Proposition.** If $N$ is an even perfect number then 
>   $$\frac{2+rad(N)}{8}\left(\sum_{\substack{d|N,d<rad(N)}}d\right)=N.$$

*Proof.* By Euler's Theorem for even perfect numbers, $$\sum_{\substack{d|N,d<rad(N)}}d=1+\cdots+2^{p-1}+(2^p-1)=2(2^p-1),$$
and $$\frac{2+rad(N)}{8}=\frac{2+2(2^p-1)}{2}=\frac{2^{p+1}}{8}=2^{p-2}.$$
And this is the end of proof (if there aren't mistakes seems short and cool).

My question is

> **Question.** What about the reciprocal statement? Can you find a counterexample?

I've made computations until $10^3$ and only find (with a computer) even perfect numbers. I sure that I've made a program in Lazarus Free Pascal, but my algorithm is bad, I tried run my program until $10^4$ but don't runs. I don't implement the parity when I divide by $8$. Only I write the condition $M$ such that $$\frac{2+rad(M)}{8}\left(\sum_{\substack{d|M,d<rad(M)}}d\right)=M$$ in my algorithm.

Please feel free to made feedback, suggestions, hints or critics are welcome. Thanks in advance.

**Update to delete a previous code, I was using this post as draf. I'm sorry.**

**References:**

Wikipedia or Mathworld pages about Perfect Numbers.

Comment: If someone can up the limit $10^3$ with a computer this is the best. Thanks

Comment: Thirdly, the numbers for which the expression in question is an integer are very many. Fourthly, if factorizing large numbers is a problem, use [this application](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Comment: Sorry, that **rad** got me all confused. :-$)$ If so, then the only numbers $\le10^5$ satisfying the original, unmodified relation are the even perfect numbers.

Comment: There are no other solutions below $10^7$. The *Mathematica* code I used is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BLZ7D.png).

Comment: Very thanks much @Lucian feel free to ask questions in new posts if in future seasons you can made conjectures. I try learn Mathematica, very thanks.